# Error in rstudio : libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, rstudio

I installed RStudio version 0.98.507 and my `R` version is  2.14.1. My OS is ubuntu 12.04. When I try to start RStudio from the terminal I get the following error:

```
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why are you using such an old R version?

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get install libuuid1
```

This command will not resolve the problem, if you are running 32 bit executable on 64 bit Ubuntu. Need to install 32 bit version of `libuuid1` with `i386' suffix.

```
apt-get install libuuid1:i386
```

---

For NixOS, you can follow this:

- [Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory #1893](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1893#issuecomment-1096988007)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libuuid1
```

Comment: I upgraded R to R version 3.1.0 still the error persist

Comment: When using aws linux and trying to install .net core `yum install libuuid` solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have some dependencies and, in fact, not completely installed.

When I tried to install, I got the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libjpeg62; however:
  Package libjpeg62 is not installed.
```

So I simply installed the dependency via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

And then installed the rstudio:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-<your_version>-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this problem, installing libuuid1 also did not work for me. This was because I had installed the 32 bit version of R studio when my system is 64 bit. So one solution is to install the 32 bit versions of the libraries, such as 'libuuid1:i386' in debian. The more simple and obvious solution is to just uninstall the current version of rstudio and install the 64 bit version. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

installing the following package solved the problem for me. I am using ubuntu 12.04

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs